# PDO_mysql driver doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using Apache server on Windows 8, XAMPP 1.8.1, PHP 5.4.7 and MySQL.
I've decided to convert my code to PDO.

Checking my *phpinfo()* it appears that the PDO driver for MySQL is enabled, but I still keep on getting the "could not find driver" error.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
//connect to database

$config['db'] = array(
    'host'           => 'localhost',
    'username'       => 'root',
    'password'       => '',
    'dbname'         => 'x'
    );

$db = new PDO("
    pdo_mysql:host=     " .$config['db']['host']. ";
    dbname=             " .$config['db']['dbname']. ";
    username=           " .$config['db']['username'].";
    password=           " .$config['db']['password']."
    ");
?>
```

And the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me suggest you to **to post in your question exact code you tried along with exact error message you've got**. To make it possible to give you some suggestions.

Comment: Because it's a driver issue I assumed the code is irrelevant, but I've added it now, hope it will help.

Comment: It cannot be driver issue as phpinfo() says driver is installed

Comment: I'm very certain it's the way you formatted your DSN string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you change the DSN prefix from `pdo_mysql` to just `mysql`?

Comment: it obviously works. while this should be a comment, not answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense *"Ain't that the Pot calling the Kettle black."* You often put in answers similar to this ([Just like yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18674400/1415724)). Although it could have been worded differently, it led to an actual "answer/solution" and that's what's "important".

Comment: @Fred-ii- I **never** ask "what happens" in the answer. Either I know what happens already, or I don't answer at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I agree, that's why I edited my comment and added "Although it could have been worded differently".

Answer (score 5):

Let me suggest you refer to the [**manual page**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) and get the **proper** DSN string example from there

Answer (score 1):

As manual says [link](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

You should format your dsn in this way:
`DRIVER:host=YOURHOST;dbname=YOURDB`

Also to create the instance you should act like this: `$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password)`

Also I forgot to say (as other users have pointed out) your DRIVER is "mysql" and not pdo_mysql

Comment: Actually it is quite different, the user is including both username and password in the DSN, while they have to be passed as parameters.

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end there were 2 problems with the code:

**1. pdo_mysql -> mysql**

**2. username and password should be passed as *variables and not as strings*.**

The correct code is:

```
$config['db'] = array(
    'host'           => 'localhost',
    'username'       => 'root',
    'password'       => '',
    'dbname'         => 'x'
    );

$db = new PDO (
    "mysql:host=".$config['db']['host'].";dbname=".$config['db']['dbname']."",
    $config['db']['username'], 
    $config['db']['password'] 
);
```